# Ajax call after 5 secs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I click on a button is it possible to call an ajax after 5 secs?

HTML :

```
<button>Click</button>
<p id='output'></p>
```

AJAX:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'save_student_db.php',
        data: 's_name=' + $('#s_name').val() +
            '&s_email=' + $('#s_email').val() +
            '&s_phone=' + $('#s_phone').val() +
            '&s_add=' + $('#s_add').val() +
            '&dept_select=' + $('#dept_select').val() +
            '&datepiker=' + $('#datepiker').val(),
        success: function(reply_data) {
            $('#output').html(reply_data);
        }
    });
});
```

Here I want when I click on the button then this ajax call will called after 5 secs. How can I do it? thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

Comment: The setimout will work, but only if the users doesn't navigate away from your page. 5 seconds is a lot of time to wait and make the assumption that the users hasn't already moved onto something else.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, like this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'save_student_db.php',
            data: 's_name='+ $('#s_name').val() + 
                  '&s_email=' + $('#s_email').val() + 
                  '&s_phone=' + $('#s_phone').val() + 
                  '&s_add=' + $('#s_add').val() + 
                  '&dept_select=' + $('#dept_select').val() + 
                  '&datepiker=' + $('#datepiker').val(),
            success: function(reply_data) { 
                $('#output').html(reply_data);
            },
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout()

setTimeout(function(){ $(".selectSomething").yourAjaxFunctionHere() }, 5000);

Comment: `setInterval` will keep firing every 5 seconds which is what OP is not looking for

Comment: The point is you should not suggest it because its the wrong thing to do. It's not worthy of a downvote though. A comment will suffice unless it's not rectified.